# AlertDialog not applying custom theme

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I would like to increase the textsize of the alert dialog message text, so I added the following styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MainActionBar</item>

        <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>

        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.Large">
        <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

However the style is not applied when displaying the dialog.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> Theme

```
 <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
            <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        </style>
```

> AlertDialog

```
    private void prompt() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(
                getActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle));
        alert.setTitle("Update SSID");
        alert.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#009688'>Do you want to update Heater SSID </font><font color='red'><u>" + Constants.WIFI_SSID.toUpperCase() + "</u></font><font color='#009688'> ?</font>"));
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        final TextView secure = new TextView(getActivity());
        secure.setTypeface(Util.setCustomFont(getActivity()));
        final EditText titleBox = new EditText(getActivity());
        titleBox.setTypeface(Util.setCustomFont(getActivity()));
        secure.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#009688'><br><b>Enter new SSID</b></font>"));
            /*Edittext setting*/
        titleBox.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(35, 5, 35, 10);
        titleBox.setLayoutParams(params);
        titleBox.setSingleLine(true);
        titleBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text);
        titleBox.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#505050"));
        titleBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
        // titleBox.setText("****************");
        titleBox.setTextSize(12);
       /*Textview setting*/
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramss = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramss.setMargins(35, 10, 35, 5);
        secure.setLayoutParams(paramss);
        layout.addView(secure);
        layout.addView(titleBox);
        alert.setView(layout);
        alert.setPositiveButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("UPDATE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setEnabled(false);
        titleBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                int ssidLength = charSequence.length();
                if (ssidLength == 0) {
                    return;
                }
                if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(charSequence.charAt(ssidLength - 1))) {
                    titleBox.getText().delete(ssidLength - 1, ssidLength);
                    return;
                }
                if (ssidLength < 2) {
                    alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setEnabled(true);
                }
                if (ssidLength > 12) {
                    titleBox.getText().delete(ssidLength - 1, ssidLength);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

    }
```

> edit_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:thickness="0dp">
    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#009688" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Comment: See my edit.try to avoid unwanted customization in my code..you can specify font size inside Html.fromHtml if required ..

Answer (score 0):

try adding parent to "TextAppearance.Large" style.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Large" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
</style>
```